# Multiple selector by Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wan to make multiple selector like this.

Choices are prepared in advance, and then user can select a few items.

[image]

At first, I think I use `<Switch>` component but this visual is different from what I want.

then I read about `<Select>` but, it is also different.

My current answer is using multiple `<Button>` , (but it looks a bit not cool...??)

Am I right?? or Is there any alternative??

Comment: You can checkout the Autocomplete component from material-ui .it provides a prop for rendering the custom options .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could help you to use ***Chip*** in material-ui[image]

and then use an array to push the newly selected item to it.

```
const [theArray, setTheArray] = useState(initialArray);
```

and in a onChange kind of function push selected item to save them

```
setTheArray([...theArray, newElement]);
```

Comment: `Chip` is quite excellent widget. That's what I want . thank you very much.